# To check if few values in dataframe column exists in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, difference

I am trying to check if values present in df1 column is present in df2 column.
df2 contains more values than df1 and cant use `for` loop

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one': [2,4,6,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'one': [4,2,6,8,10]})

print(df1.isin(df2))
```

expected results

```
    one
0  True
1  True
2   True
3   True
```

actual results

```
     one
0  False
1  False
2   True
3   True
```

2 and 4 are present in df2 , still due to order false is given. is there a way where order of values don't impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare columns:

```
print(df1['one'].isin(df2['one']))  
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: one, dtype: bool
```

Or convert values of DataFrame to 1d array and then list:

```
print(df1.isin(df2.to_numpy().ravel().tolist()))  
    one
0  True
1  True
2  True
3  True
```